# How to set default table storage engine in MySQL using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

I'm using `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` and would like to set InnoDB as the default storage engine for all my databases instead of the default MyISAM, but have no idea to do so in EFC code-first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an opened issue in `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` that an engine cannot be specified: [link](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/84).

And on that page there is a workaround posted as: to use migrations instead of `EnsureDatabaseCreated`, and manually to set `default_storage_engine` variable to `InnoDB`during migration db session: [link to the workaround](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/84#issuecomment-473794411).